# PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: Can't find bundle for base name org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.CucumberBundle, locale en_US

Tags: java, android, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am setting up BDD testing in my application using Cucumber. Since I installed the Gherkin plugin for recognizing feature files and scripts I have been receiving this error that reads

```
PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: Can't find bundle for base name org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.CucumberBundle, locale en_US
```

It occurs each time that I open a feature file.

Any experience with this error in the past?

Comment: It sounds as if you may have found a bug in InteliJ or the Gherkin plugin. I would ask Jetbrains. Maybe you have an interesting, as in not working, combination of versions.

Comment: @ThomasSundberg sounds largely feasible as Ive tried every in my logic to fix the issue.